# Inner Border With Different Values Each

Tags: css

How can I made inner border with different values each? For example:

Top: 20px
Right: 80px
Bottom: 40px
Left: 10px

Example that what I want made...

[image]

Thank you. :)

Comment: Did you try `border-top:...` `border-right:...` ?

Comment: It's only for outer border and not inner border. :)

Comment: there is no such thing as *inner* border. you only simulate it using hacks. it would be better if you could edit your question to show what hack you are currently using to simulate an inner border.

Comment: Hi @Yiedpozi, please check my answer out and let me know if that helps ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it an inner border, use two box-shadows on the element, separated with a comma, and use negative values on the second set.
Like this:

```
box-shadow: inset 10px 20px 0px #000, inset -80px -40px 0px #000;
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dr_lucas/23Egu/326/

This is the cross-browser compatible CSS:

```
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 10px 20px 0px #000, inset -80px -40px 0px #000;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 10px 20px 0px #000, inset -80px -40px 0px #000;
box-shadow:inset 10px 20px 0px #000, inset -80px -40px 0px #000;
```

Note that if you need it to be compatible with old IE versions that don't support box-shadow, you can use CSS3pie:
http://css3pie.com/

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using `box-shadow`

[Here is an example how i've used it](http://jsfiddle.net/r7wGT/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Inner border: Do you mean padding?

If so:

`padding: 20px 80px 40px 10px;` // top left bottom right

Else if you really meant border then:

```
border-top: 20px solid #color;
border-right: 80px solid #color;
border-left: 10px solid #color;
border-bottom: 40px solid #color;
```

It can be achieved via CSS3 box-shadow also